# Showing the set $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is neither open nor closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Define the set $E$ as $E= \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \dots \} = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{\frac{1}{n}\}.$

Prove that $E$ is neither open nor closed.

While I understand that being open and closed is not mutually exclusive, I am not sure how to go about  this.

Comment: I removed your references to series because this isn't a series - a series is a sum, and this is a sequence/set you're dealing with here - and the fact that the harmonic series is divergent is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

It is not closed because $0$ is a limit point but it does not belong to the set.

It is not open because if you take any ball around $\frac{1}{n}$ it will not be completely contained in the set ( as it will contain points which are not of the form $\frac1n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, but $0\notin E$. What do you know about sets that don't contain all of their limit points?

Next, consider $1\in E$. Any open set $U$ containing $1$ must contain points larger than $1$. Thus, $U\nsubseteq E$. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are under the usual topology on the real line. Note that it can proved that a subset $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed iff $F = \overline{F}$; and $\overline{F} = F \cup F'$ where $F'$ denotes the set of all accumulation points of $F$.  Note that $1/n \to 0$; so $0$ is an accumulation point of $\{1/n\}$. Note that $0 \notin \{ 1/n \}$; so $\{ 1/n \}$ is not closed.

Note that between every pair of rational numbers there is some irrational number; so there is no open ball of center $1/2$ that is included in $\{ 1/n \}$, and hence $\{ 1/n \}$ is not open by definition.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is not open because $1\in E$ but there is no $r>0$ such that $(-r+1,r+1)\subset E.

$E$ is not closed because its complement $E^c$ is not open because $0\in E^c$ but there is no $r>0$ such that $(-r+0,r+0)\subset E^c.$ Because for any $r>0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ and $1/n<r$, implying that there exists $1/n\in E\cap (-r,r).$